# Countdown function in flutterflow

Tags: dart, countdown, custom-function, flutterflow

How can you implement a countdown inside of flutterflow with the help of custom functions and the timer widget?

In the end we need to have hours, minutes and seconds visible. The countdown should end at 00:00:00.

The future date and time is a value inside of supabase and we need to subtract the now date and time.

My friend and me are trying for 6 hours for this to work, but either the code is wrong or the timer shows strange numbers. Would very appreciate some input as we can't seem to find it somewhere else.

We tried converting time in database and now time in milliseconds and outputting the into the timer widget.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom function that takes DateTime value from firebase and returns the countdown value in milliseconds (ms). and then you can call this custom function in Timer widget.

here is the snippet for custom code if you need it.

```
int countdownms(DateTime timestamp) {

  int currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  int targetTime = timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  int countdown = targetTime - currentTime;
  return countdown > 0 ? countdown : 0;

}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJE1c.png)

Hope this helps. cheers